# Reset Graphics2D object in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I was experimenting with Graphics2D in Java. But as usual, I am stuck. :P The problem is:
Suppose i have this code,

```
Graphics2D g=(Graphics2D)(this.getGraphics()); //Inside a JFrame
g.rotate(Math.PI/8);
g.drawLine(10, 20, 65, 80);

//I want this one and all following lines to be drawn without any rotation
g.drawLine(120, 220, 625, 180);
```

Is it possible??? I know there must be some way but I am not able to figure it out. Please help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you'll want to do is restore the transform.

Try

```
AffineTransform oldXForm = g.getTransform();
g.rotate(...);
g.drawLine(...);

g.setTransform(oldXForm); // Restore transform
g.drawLine(...);
```

Comment: In addition, it's recommended that you use a copy of the graphics object, rather than the graphics object itself to avoid clobbering since this will be used elsewhere.

Comment: can u please explain?? what do you mean by clobbering?

Comment: Sometimes you already have a `Graphics` object and you want to change some of its state temporarily and then return it to its original state. One approach is to create a new `Graphics` object that is a copy of the original one and to make changes to that copy instead. This technique avoids clobbering the state of the original object, which other parts of Swing may depend on. It may not be applicable in this case, but I figured it wouldn't hurt to mention! :)

Comment: It's generally preferred to make the copy rather than modify and restore, mainly for performance reasons.

Comment: I got it. And your solution was of course the best for the answer asked but it dint served my purpose well. setTransform() just resets the existing drawn objects as well. Maybe my fault somewhere. But as soon as I tried your Graphics object copy method (to avoid clobbing), it worked like miracle!!!

Comment: You can use affineTransform.setToIdentity(); rather than use oldXForm.

Answer (score 5):

Call `getTransform()` (gives you a copy), rotate, draw, and then use `setTransform()` to restore the state. The [docs for `setTransform()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setTransform%28java.awt.geom.AffineTransform%29) even have an example.