# Rotating text in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt, graphics2d, image-rotation

I'm creating a wheel of fortune game in java for a college project. I am struggling to get my image rotation down. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what is showing with the code below:

[image]

**WHEEL_COLOURS** - an ArrayList of 18 Colours

**WHEEL_VALUES** - a String array of 18 values including Lose a Turn, 500, 1000 etc.

**ANGLE** = 20 (360/18 segments)

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // draw wheel
    for (Color c : WHEEL_COLOURS) {
        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillArc(5, 15, wheelSize, wheelSize, degrees, ANGLE);
        degrees += ANGLE;
    }


    for(int i=0; i< WHEEL_VALUES.length; i++) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        drawRotate(g2d, 125, 125, degrees, WHEEL_VALUES[i]);
        degrees += ANGLE;
    }

    // draw pointer
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.fillArc(100, 0, 40, 60, 67, 45);
    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    g.drawArc(100, 0, 40, 60, 67, 45);

}

public static void drawRotate(Graphics2D g2d, double x, double y, int angle, String text) 
{    
    g2d.translate((float)x,(float)y);
    g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle));
    g2d.drawString(text,0,0);
    g2d.rotate(-Math.toRadians(angle));
    g2d.translate(-(float)x,-(float)y);
}
```

Comment: *FYI:* Instead of undoing the `translate` + `rotate` by reapplying in reverse, save the state before and restore it, as described in this answer: [Reset Graphics2D object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6681641/5221149) (read the comments too).

Comment: Seems the text is rotating correctly, but you'd want to right-align the text, so it is aligned with the outer edge of the circle, not left-aligned at the center. Closing with link showing how to right-align, where the `rightEdge` would be the radius of the circle, i.e. `wheelSize / 2`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem. Snippets of incomplete code don't help.

Comment: Text is WAY more complex to render that you might think.  Start by having a look at [Graphics 2D/Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/text.html) and [Working with Text APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html) for some more details

Comment: One of the things I would do, so set up your text rendering so it works "normally" at a position of 0x0 and then use something like `AffineTransform` to change the origin and rotation

Comment: I would suggest you draw your wheel into a separate Image and then rotate the image.  You may also want to turn on anti-aliasing with Graphics2D.RenderingHints() to smooth out the rough edges.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, this gives me a few things to read up on.